# Windows IoT Core GpioController - assembly 'Windows' causes a cycle

Tags: gpio, windows-iot, assembly

I am trying my new Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 IoT Core.

I have fallowed the steps of the installations and cofigurations, and every thing was fine until I've got to Blanky tutorial

http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/Blinky.htm

I am trying to get GpioController instance in my universal app:
var gpioController = Windows.Devices.Gpio.GpioController.getDefault();

And I am getting two errors:

> Error CS0731 The type forwarder for type
>   'Windows.Devices.Gpio.GpioController' in assembly 'Windows' causes a
>   cycle IOT.POC C:\Users\Pavel\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\IOT.POC\IOT.POC\MainPage.xaml.cs 26
>
> Error CS1069 The type name 'GpioController' could not be found in the
>   namespace 'Windows.Devices.Gpio'. This type has been forwarded to
>   assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' Consider adding a
>   reference to that assembly. IOT.POC C:\Users\Pavel\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2015\Projects\IOT.POC\IOT.POC\MainPage.xaml.cs 26

However, when I am adding the using for the namespace:
using Windows.Devices.Gpio;

I don't get any errors at all...

I also don't the namespace Windows.Devices.Gpio under Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract namespace...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add Microsoft IoT Extension SDK?

[image: Reference Manager - Windows Universal Extensions]

Comment: I've added the Windows IoT Extension SDK (it was already there in the  blinky project) and it still won't find Windows.Devices.Gpio with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 fully patched. W/hat am I doing wrong?